# Android store valid dates (not dates in past)

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker

Not sure why, but Im trying to set a valid (one that isn't in the past). This works in some cases, e.g. set to April 4th  2014, however if I am setting it from Feb 28th 2014 to March 2nd 2014, It is saying the date is a  date in the past. Can someone see why this is the case?

```
public class StartDatePicker extends DialogFragment implements
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int startYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int startMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int startDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the date picker
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this,
                startYear, startMonth, startDay);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {




        // disable past dates

        if (year < startYear || monthOfYear < startMonth
                || dayOfMonth < startDay) {
            DialogFragment dialogFragment = new StartDatePicker();
            dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                    "start_date_picker");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select Valid Date",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

//store date

}}
```

Comment: forgot to mention, I am using a datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if selected date is in past use the following:

on your onDateSet function - create a calendar instance and :

```
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,monthOfYear);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);
```

After setting a calendar with the date picked, check if it's past/after your current time using System.timeInMilliseconds()

```
if (calendar.getTimeInMilliseconds() < System.timeInMilliseconds()) {
  // Your implementation ... 
}
```

Hope it helpes...good luck